# How to stop a process in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, process, kill

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ending a process in unix instead of interrupting it](https://superuser.com/questions/97261/ending-a-process-in-unix-instead-of-interrupting-it)

When I task in Terminal, such as `ping blah.com`, how do I then stop this task (other than closing the Terminal window.  In Windows, you can Ctrl+Break pretty much any terminal based process, but I can't figure out the way to do it on the Mac.

Comment: This was useful to me coming from Linux. I had no idea Ctrl+Break was what I needed on Windows :)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Ctrl + C is a the standard *nix way of signaling a process to abort.

Comment: My Mac just beeps at me when I try this.

Comment: Mr. Tea: are you using Command instead of Control?

Comment: @heavyd, Why does `man` use `q` instead of ctrlC to quit? What's the rationale?

Comment: @Pacerier, I can't really say why, you'd have to talk to the developers to figure that out.  Processes can capture the Ctrl + C signal and do something else if they choose, but by default the behavior of Ctrl + C is abort the process.

Comment: Ctrl + c does not work on zsh, MacOS Catalina.

Comment: Command + . is how you do it in Mac Terminal

Answer (score 47):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> might help if you want to **suspend** a process.

For further information, `man kill`.

If you're curious about the difference between suspend and terminate, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266388/2229) is a good starting point; the TL;DR version is, a suspended process can be resumed later and its execution can continue. A terminated (and killed) process will be gone.

Comment: Ctrl + c  or ctrl + z does not work on zsh, MacOS Catalina.

Comment: Try CMD + (.) period/dot

Comment: CMD + (.) period/dot works!