# What is the terminal command other than ctrl + c to exit a running Node.js program in a macOS?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, terminal

In Linux terminal if I run a command like:

```
$ node httserver.js
```

The command runs and by doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> the program is terminated and new line comes in terminal for us to enter a command.

I felt <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> as the macOS terminal keyboard combo to do that but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a process in Terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/103909/how-to-stop-a-process-in-terminal)

Answer (score 49):

The accurate answer for MAC Keyboard on terminal is:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (dot/period)

This is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or break.

Refer to the:

> Terminal Help > Keyboard Shortcuts > Other Shortcuts > Break

The <kbd>Control</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is *not* a regular modifier in macOS.

However, if you are using a regular Windows keyboard with macOS then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> works since there is no <kbd>Command</kbd> key in this case.

Comment: confirmed, other answers seem to be confused.  Command+. works in OS X (Mac) Terminal application for sending an interrupt with a Mac keyboard.  Control+C, Control+Z, Shift+Command+C, kill commands do not work in this setting.  you cannot send a kill command while another command is actively running.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

It should be the same as Linux.

Duplicate of: [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/103909/how-to-stop-a-process-in-terminal)

Comment: Ctrl + c is actually intercepted by macOs to open settings

Answer (score 7):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

Or you can use `kill` Command. For further information see `man kill` command for manual of kill command and you can get some guidance from this [link](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/06/04/how-to-kill-a-program-or-process-in-os-x/) about how to use `kill` command.

Comment: ctrl-z does NOT do this. And "Or you can use the kill command" does not make any sense. Ctrl-Z and kill are completely and utterly different. I dont think you know what Ctrl-z does

Comment: I found this worked in visual studio for mac terminal session

Answer (score 3):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> worked for a friend.

Comment: This opens the color picker on my system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iterm2, you might need to look into *Preferences* -> *Keys* -> *Remap Modifiers*. In my case, *control (^)* was mapped to something else by default. After mapping it to *control (^)*, the shortcut worked.

Answer (score 0):

Typing `Ctrl` + `h` took me to a help thing where it showed me the letter to type to exit.
In my case, it indicated I had to use `Ctrl` + `q`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using VSCode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> works just fine.